# How do I set up drag and drop in getorgchart?

Tags: getorgchart

When I enable drag and drop in getorgchart I'm able to click and drag a node but there is no drop action. It just looks like I'm dragging an image but when I release the mouse button to drop it, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Set enableDragDrop option to true

```
enableDragDrop: true
```

Comment: When i enableDragDrop: true, that's when i'm not able to do anything but drag without any drop action taking place.